# Linear Algebra: Find four unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the same angle between each.

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I need to determine the set of all angles $\theta$ such that there exists some four distinct unit vectors $\vec{v}_1, ..., \vec{v}_4 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and the angle between any $\vec{v_i}$ and $\vec{v_j}$ is $\theta$ if $i\ne j$.  I cannot geometrically imagine an instance of this, although I can pretty easily see examples for three distinct vectors.  If you have two vectors, you can easily add a third such that its angle with the other two is equal to the angle of the first two.  But if you have three vectors of equal pair-wise angle, I can't see any way to rearrange or place a fourth so that they share the same angle.

The dot-product sounds relevant since any vector dotted with itself is 1, and dotted with any other vector is $\cos\theta$.  I've seen the trick enough times to suspect that I form the matrix $A^TA$ where the columns of $A$ are the vectors.  Then

$$A^TA = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cos\theta & \cos\theta & ... & \cos\theta \\
\cos\theta & 1 & \cos \theta & ... & \cos\theta \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
\cos\theta & \cos\theta & ... & \cos\theta & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

That is to say, 1s down the main diagonal, $\cos\theta$ everywhere else. It's a symmetric matrix, but I'm not sure what to do with it.  I could take the determinant but I'm not sure what that would give me.

Comment: @Masacroso:  I don't think so.  If we choose $\theta=\frac \pi 2$ the first three vectors might as well be $\hat x, \hat y, \hat z$.  Now where is the fourth?

Comment: Hint: regular tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you guessed actually works: As you noted yourself, an eigendecomposition of the inner product matrix $G=G_{\theta}$ (which is typically called Gramian matrix, by the way) is, with $x:=\cos(\theta)$,

$$
G=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &0\\
1 &-1 &1 &0\\
1 &0 &-1 &1 \\
1 &0  &0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+3x & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1-x & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1-x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1-x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &0\\
1 &-1 &1 &0\\
1 &0 &-1 &1 \\
1 &0  &0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
If there exists a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}$ such that $G=A^{\top}A$, then $G$ can have at most rank $3$. Since the left and right matrices above are independent of $x$ and full rank, the middle matrix must have rank $3$. This can only happen if $x=1$ (which is a trivial case I leave to you) or when $x=-1/3$. This already proves the first bit:

**If a solution exists, we must have $x=-1/3$ or $\theta=\arccos(-1/3)=109.5 ^{\circ} $.**

To prove that there is a solution, i.e a matrix $A$ such that $G_{109.5}=A^{\top}A$, note that for $x=-1/3$ you have a positive semi-definite matrix. Such matrices have a decomposition as $A^{\top}A$ for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}$; you could use the singular value decomposition to prove this. $\Box$

Practically, you can find $A$ as follows:

Write the eigenvector matrix from above be
$$
(v_1|V_2)
$$
where $v_1=(1,1,1,1)$ and $V_2$ is the remaining $3\times 4$ part. Find an orthonormal basis of that part to get a new matrix $\tilde{V_2}$ of eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $1-x$. Since
$$
M=(v_1/2|\tilde{V_2})
$$
is an orthonormal basis, you have
$$
G=MDM^{-1}=MDM^{\top}.
$$
with $D$ the middle matrix from above. Since the first entry of $D$ is zero, this reduces to
$$
\tilde{V_2}\tilde{D}\tilde{V_2}^{\top}=(\tilde{V_2}\sqrt{\tilde{D}})(\sqrt{\tilde{D}}\tilde{V_2})^{\top},
$$
where you can read off the solution $A:=(\sqrt{\tilde{D}}\tilde{V_2})^{\top}$.

Comment: I went into computing the determinant and see a pattern, but it's not obvious to me.  I can see that when expanding along the first row, the first cofactor is a smaller version of the whole determinant.  Every other cofactor can be permuted to be the same as each other, and so these just sum together.  But then there remains finding these cofactors.  Am I supposed to solve a recursive formula in order to do this without computing the entire determinant?

Comment: Sorry, I'm now noticing you didn't mean to compute the determinant but rather compute the eigenvalues.  I'm not sure of a relationship between the eigenvalues of a matrix and its determinant but I'll think about it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was so mysterious. The determinant won't help you find all eigenvalues, but in your case the determinant is actually enough: you'll find that the determinant is only zero for one nontrivial (i.e. not $\theta=k2\pi$) angle, and that angle is your solution: The determinant must be zero becuaee your matrix can only have rank 3 as product of rank 3 matrices.

Comment: I still don't think I fully get it but here's how I'm currently approaching it: The determinant must be zero, I get that.  The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.  One of the eigenvalues is zero, and it corresponds to how you could use Guassian elimination to get a zero row.  I'm thinking of the matrix like one with value $a$ down the main diagonal and $b$ everywhere else.  A vector of all 1s will be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $a+b(n-1)$.  After that, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing.

Comment: Actually, I'm now seeing that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\...\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector and likewise for several permutations of this, each with eigenvalue $a-b$. So the determinant is $0=0(a-b)^{n-1}$.  I'm still not seeing the significance of this though.

Comment: Just look at the first eigenvalue you mentioned. It shows that 1=3cos(\theta) which shows that if there is a solution it is arccos(1/3). The fact that a solution exists follows from the cholesky decomposition of your positive semi definite matrix

Comment: I'm not seeing how an eigenvalue of 0 implies what you say. Is this related back to the determinant? The only other thing I can think of is going back to the definition of an eigenvalue.

Comment: Let me expand my answer in some more detail

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ are such vectors. I claim that $v_2 - v_1, v_3 - v_1, v_4 - v_1$ form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. It suffices to prove that they are linearly independent.

Suppose $a_2(v_2 - v_1) + a_3(v_3 - v_1) + a_4(v_4 - v_1) = 0$. Dot producting with $v_i$ (where $i = 2, 3, 4$), this becomes
$$a_i(1 - \cos(\theta)) = 0 \implies a_i = 0,$$
as clearly $\cos(\theta) = 1$ fails to make the vectors distinct. Therefore, the vectors are linearly independent in $\Bbb{R}^3$, and are thus a basis.

Let $w = v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4$. I now claim that $w = 0$. Note first that,
$$w \cdot v_i = 1 + 3\cos(\theta),$$
and hence
$$w \cdot (v_i - v_j) = 0.$$
In particular, $w$ is perpendicular to all three basis vectors from before, proving $w = 0$ as required.

Since $0 = w \cdot v_1 = 1 + 3\cos(\theta)$, we must have $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{1}{3}$.